# Puzzle over sudo and paths

Tags: sudo, path

I have a couple of programmes which are in `/usr/local/bin` which require root privileges to run.

If I run

```
sudo my_prog
```

I get

```
sudo: my_prog: command not found
```

I have to write

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/my_prog
```

for the programme to work.

Could anybody explain to me why I have to do this? `/usr/local/bin` is in the root's `$PATH` and in mine.

Comment: Check for the `execute` permission on `my_prog`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's -rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   90536 Feb  2 17:32 - everyone can read and run.

Comment: It's possible that on your system, `sudo` policy sets `PATH` to something that doesn't include `/usr/local/bin`. If that's the case, it doesn't matter what `root`'s PATH is set to. Try running `sudo -E my_prog` and see what happens.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. If I use the -E flag, it does request my root password before reporting that my_prog hasn't been found. Without the -E, it immediately comes back with the not found message. `[pol@localhost inst]$ sudo -E my_prog
[sudo] password for pol: 
sudo: my_prog: command not found
[pol@localhost inst]$ sudo my_prog
sudo: my_prog: command not found
[pol@localhost inst]$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `/usr/local/bin` in the root's `$PATH`
but just doing `sudo` does not give you root's profile where that `PATH` is set

you will get it after logging on as root with

```
su -
```

or

```
sudo -i
```

Those give you a root shell.

If you want to stay on one line, try using

```
sudo su -c 'my_prog'
```

if that doesnt work enforce it  with -l

```
sudo su -l -c 'my_prog'
```

Comment: `[pol@localhost test]$ sudo su -c 'my_prog'
[sudo] password for pol: 
bash: my_prog: command not found`  It still doesn't find it. `sudo -c '/usr/local/bin/my_prog` however does work.

Comment: it may depend on how the PATH in root's profile is set

please try following
sudo su -l -c 'my_prog'

Comment: `sudo su -l -c 'my_prog'` - this works! A brief explanation of what exactly is going on would be appreciated.

Comment: -l switch forces the shell session to be a login session, that in turn forces the root's profile to be loaded. Apparently root's profile file is where the PATH variable is set/modified, so your command will be searched on the root's PATH.

Tip: try omit the sudo in front - it might be unneeded.

Comment: You are correct, it is uneeded. I'll take some time to read up on these commands - but you get the bonus! Thanks.